# Need help identifying Century like font

Tags: typography, font-identification

The G is round, the M has vertical legs and a high V and the R has straight legs. Thought it could be Century or Futura but ...

[image: This is an excerpt of a brazilian]

Comment: Seems to be OCR B but has an almost circular O

Comment: The image is taken from an official paper such as driving licence. They can use custom typefaces which are not generally for sale as computer fonts. If the paper is yours try to get a sharper image, for ex with 400% pixel dimensions. It's impossible to see does letter I have serifs and the exact ends of S and C.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. With such a bad resolution it is impossible to be assertive. It seems that the printing varies but other samples gave me better clues.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with such a small sample but it's probably Avant Garde Bold.

Comment: Avant Garde M has a low neck